# NotNull constraints aren't being enforced when not set

Tags: validation, spring-data-elasticsearch

NotNull constraints aren't being enforced, when the attribute is not set. Is there anything which needs to be additionally set to enforce null values

```
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

    @NotNull(message = "PaymentType is required")
    @JsonProperty(PAYMENT_TYPE)
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, name = PAYMENT_TYPE)
    private PaymentType paymentType;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are having a `@JsonProperty(PAYMENT_TYPE)` annotation on that property I assume you are using this entity not only to store data in Elasticsearch, but also are sending it to and receiving from some client application? Then the validation should happen when you get this data in. Spring Data Elasticsearch does not support validation on properties.

Comment: Yes it is consumed over a REST endpoint as well. Are you suggesting we specifically use a system defined JSR 303 validator to validator the entity in the controller

Comment: yes, it would make more sense to validate incoming data before sending it to a backend. But support for JSR-303 might be an interesting feature to add to Spring Data Elasticsearch